# Opentip styling doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, opentip

I using [opentip](http://www.opentip.org/) and I tried to style the opentip with custom styling.

These are my code inside coffee.

```
Opentip.styles.orangetip = { 
  stem: true,
  borderColor: "#ffa358",
  borderWidth: "50",
  background: "#ffa358",
  fixed: true,
  stemLength: "10"
  }
```

And I even use this block to make my styling as default, but it still doesn't work.

```
Opentip.defaultStyle = "orangetip"
```

This is my script to call the style.

```
tip1 = new Opentip("#testong", "Optional content", { 
  style: "orangetip", 
  showOn: "mouseover"
})
```

Style doesn't load, but showOn is working. As example if I change "mouseover" into "click", the container will showing with click, not hover.

Anyone know why the style doesn't load? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I already found the answer.

The problem is because I using "" for integer value.

So, it must be :

```
Opentip.styles.orangetip = { 
  stem: true,
  borderColor: "#ffa358",
  borderWidth: 50,
  background: "#ffa358",
  fixed: true,
  stemLength: 10
}
```